# Select text with just one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I wrote this JS code with some jQuery and got a one-click-text-selection. Maybe someone can improve this code, because I think it's not "clean" and short engough ;) But I don't want to use an input field. Let me know if you have some ideas!

```
function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document,
        text = doc.getElementById(element),
        range,
        selection;
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
$(function() {
    $('p').click(function () {
        SelectText('autoselect');
    });
});
```

And this is the HTML part:

```
<div id="autoselect">
    <p>Some cool text!</p>
</div>
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/QLvxL/1/) the code in a fiddle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can further improve this by [making it a jQuery plugin](http://jsbin.com/oXetAcI/4/edit) instead to make it reusable across any element.

[non-IE browsers, combined, account for ~60% of users at the time of writing](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser-ww-monthly-200807-201510). This means 60% of the time, the two conditions are evaluated since you check for IE first. Instead, reverse the conditions to get it right on the first check 60% of the time.

```
$.fn.OneClickSelect = function () {
  return $(this).on('click', function () {

    // In here, "this" is the element

    var range, selection;

    if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
      range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(this);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
      range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(this);
      range.select();
    }
  });
};

// Apply to these elements
$('p, #all-select').OneClickSelect();
```

Comment: You have always good ideas! Thank you! :)

Comment: How did you know 60% of users are using non-IE browsers? [IE has been the dominant browser in the market.](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=1&qpcustomb=0&qpsp=2013&qpnp=3&qptimeframe=Y)